# Questions about adding metadata to a CNN using keras

Tags: keras, convolutional-neural-network, metadata

I have a convolutional neural network and would like to include some metadata. My metadata is in a multiple csv files that correspond to each class and it contains a bunch of geometric properties (about 8 numerical measurements), specifically revolving around size and volume that would help classification of similar looking images but have varying size and volume. I am currently using Keras to build my models.

What I am unsure of is where and how to add metadata into my model? Do I need to combine all csv's, do I keep them separate similar to to training images file folders or something else?

What happens to the metadata when the I shuffle the images?

What happens to the metadata when I augment the images?

Comment: In your dataset images:  In one image had one class or multiple?

Comment: I have one main folder will several sub-folders with images for each class.

Comment: So "several sub-folders with images for each class" - you can use `.flow_from_directory` .  Then you no need to consider csv metadata.

Comment: Ok, but I want to include csv metadata.